# How To Update A Table Column with A Sub Query Match, using details from the Target Table?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that's basically got this setup:

[image]

The customer records have many address records associated to them, and have an internal_id text value.

The orders also have a single ship to address record associated to them.

However, I had a bug, and I'm hoping to solve this issue without code.

I need to match the name, address_one and city against the address record on the customer (they should have only 1 match) and assign the internal_id from that to the address on the orders address record.

I've tried this, but it's not working so far:

```
UPDATE address AS addr
LEFT JOIN Orders AS O ON addr.id = O.ship_to_id
SET addr.`internal_id` = (
    SELECT internal_id (
    SELECT *
    FROM address
    WHERE address.name = addr.name
    AND address.`address_line_one` = addr.`address_line_one`
    AND address.`city` = addr.`city`
) AS a_int_id)
WHERE O.deleted_at IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried creating another table?
for example: `customers_address_table`
with columns:

```
cus_add_id     pk

customer_id 

address_id
```

then in your `orders` table:

```
ship_id   pk

cus_add_id
```